# Как изменить скорость течения времени в системе?

Tags: ос

Понятно, что на аппаратном уровне это достижимо.
Возможно ли сделать это на программном уровне: изменив драйвер системного таймера или вроде того?

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, объясните-ка поподробнее, что именно Вы имеете в виду, говоря об измерении времени.

IMHO, говоря о времени, имеет смысл говорить о том, сколько раз между двумя событиями (именно об интервале времени между ними обычно и имеется в виду) произошло некое другое переодически повторяющееся событие.

В системе это может быть такт какого-то генератора. 

Так вот, об измерении чего именно Вы спрашиваете (и тут уж лучше спустится к какой-то конкретной системе).

Comment: @avp, я объясню на примере: например некая программа написана так, что каждую секунду в ней происходит какое-то событие. Можно ли не изменяя эту программу, но имея возможность изменить ОС добиться того, чтобы программа думала, что она тикает раз в секунду, а фактически тикала каждые 10 секунд ?  
ОС Linux.  
Возможно кстати есть виртуализаторы, которые позволяют это, просто я об этом не знаю.

Comment: @avp, а программа может напрямую обращаться к устройству таймера, минуя системные библиотеки? Программа запускается от имени обычного пользователя.

Comment: вообще вроде как dosbox помогает запускать стааарые программы. я к тому, что можено посмотреть как там это реализовано. Хотя вроде ээто не всем программам помогает...

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, к [Time Stamp Counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) (команда rdtsc) точно может:

    static inline unsigned long long tick() {
    unsigned long long d;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=A" (d) );
       return d;
    }

Только как его значения переводить в секунды, я не изучал.

Comment: Если это линукс, вполне возможно, что у вас ест; исходники «атакуемой» программы. Не проще ли в этом случае просто подправить её код?

Кстати, у программы может быть много источников времени. Например, ntp-сервер или usb-dongle со встроенным независимым источником.

Comment: Подправить программу не получиться: в ней все завязано на время. Проще исправить систему.

Comment: @ReinRaus: ну, почему же. «Исправление» системы может иметь неожиданные последствия. Например, рассинхрон с ntp, нарушение работы task scheduler'а, неправильная работа tcp-стека (таймауты!). А вот найти все места, где программа получает текущее время (это всё время одна и та же функция, верно?) и заменить её через `#define` на свою функцию — вполне нормальное, локальное, честное решение.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну, если менять исходник ОС (или библиотеки, которую использует эта программа), то запросто.

Только все остальные программы тоже "замедлятся" в 10 раз.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще же зависит от того каким образом прикладная программа измеряет интервалы времени.
Если это происходит через использование ф-ций операционной системы, то их, очевидно, можно перехватить и возвращаемые значения скорректировать в нужную сторону. Если же прикладная программа использует какие-либо аппаратные возможности (например, инструкцию rdtsc), то опять же все возможно - ведь как-то люди используют виртуализацию и пишут гипервизоры и виртуальные машины. Но это совсем другой уровень сложности.